# How to Select Last three Characters in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to select the last three characters of a string in xslt.

Example# if the string has "IAMFINE" I need the output as "INE"
         if String has "MYNAMEIS" I need the out as "EIS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(., string-length(.) -2)" />
```